# Changing the colour of a popup Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I've got the below popup in one of my screens and I can't workout how to change the background colour of the popup, it just defaults to the Kivy standard grey. I've tried background_colour but it changed the entire screen behind instead.

```
def none_selected(self):
        pop = Popup(title='Error',
                    content=Label(text='Please select at least one option', multiline=True,),
                    size_hint=(None, None), size=(250, 200))
        pop.open()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are content to just change the background color of the `Label` portion of the `Popup`, you can just define your own `Label` subclass:

```
class MyLabel(Label):
    pass
```

and in your 'kv':

```
<MyLabel>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Then, using `MyLabel` instead of `Label` in your `Popup` will give you a red background (but not for the title area of the `Popup`).

If you want to change the background color for the entire `Popup`, I think you will need to redefine the pre-defined style for the `Popup`. Again, create a subclass of `Popup`:

```
class MyPopup(Popup):
    bg_color = ListProperty([0,0,0,1])
```

The `bg_color` will become the background color.
Now redefine the style:

```
<-MyPopup>:
    _container: container
    GridLayout:
        padding: '12dp'
        cols: 1
        size_hint: None, None
        pos: root.pos
        size: root.size

        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: root.bg_color
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            text: root.title
            color: root.title_color
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1] + dp(16)
            text_size: self.width - dp(16), None
            font_size: root.title_size
            font_name: root.title_font
            halign: root.title_align

        Widget:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(4)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: root.bg_color
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: root.separator_color
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.x, self.y + root.separator_height / 2.
                    size: self.width, root.separator_height

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: root.bg_color
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            id: container
```

The `-` at the start of the above `kv`, indicate that we are redefining the default style (most of the above `kv` is copied from the default `style.kv`). The use of `canvas.before` sets the background color. The `MyPopup` now has a `bg_color` property that you can set to whatever color you want, for example, to set the background to red:

```
def none_selected(self):
        pop = MyPopup(title='Error',
                    content=Label(text='Please select at least one option', multiline=True,),
                    size_hint=(None, None), size=(250, 200), bg_color=[1,0,0,1])
        pop.open()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll give this a go